# HTML split list based on innerHTML of <p> inside of the <li> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-lists, multiple-columns

I have a list. Each item in the list contain a `<p>` element with the same class.
What I want to do is split the li tags into two columns based on the innerHTML value of the p elements.
For example:

```
<li class="list-li">
  <span>Data</Span>
  <p class="test">Book</p>
</li>
<li class="list-li">
  <span>Data</Span>
  <p class="test">Article</p>
</li>
<li class="list-li">
  <span>Data</Span>
  <p class="test">eBook</p>
</li>
<li class="list-li">
  <span>Data</Span>
  <p class="test">Article</p>
</li>
```

What I need is to create an algorithm that checks for the innerHTML of the p tags. If those are eBooks or Books, then the li will go to the left column. If they are anything else, they will go to the right column.

I thought of using simple CSS multi-column to create the columns but I'm not sure I can split the li tags into different columns using that method.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done?

Thank you

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.list-li').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
   innerHTML = $this.find('.test').html();
    (innerHTML === 'Book' || innerHTML === 'eBook') ? 
      $this.appendTo('.left') : $this.appendTo('.right');
  });
});
```

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.list-li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.half-col {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.half-col:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="list-li">
  <span>Data</span>
  <p class="test">Book</p>
</li>
<li class="list-li">
  <span>Data</span>
  <p class="test">Article</p>
</li>
<li class="list-li">
  <span>Data</span>
  <p class="test">eBook</p>
</li>
<li class="list-li">
  <span>Data</span>
  <p class="test">Article</p>
</li>

<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <div class="half-col left">
  
  </div>
  <div class="half-col right">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, it might work!
I don't have direct control of the HTML but I might be able to create the divs inside the ul element via javascript.
I'll give it a try and tell you how it went!

Thank you

Comment: This worked great!
I had to twik it a little to append the DIVs because I don't control the page layout, but once that was taken care of your solution worked like a charm!

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking but if I want to first check if there are any books/ebooks and only if there are run the function, how do I add that?
Because as it is now, the function splits the screen even when there are no books and I end up with a completely empty column.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function () {
  $( "li:last" ).after(function() {
    return "<td id='left'> </td><td id='right'> </td>";
  });

  $("li ").each(function () {
    if($(this).find('p').text()!="Book" & $(this).find('p').text()!="eBook"){
      $(this).appendTo('#right');
    } else {
      $(this).appendTo('#left');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.test{
  width:100px;
}

span{
  padding-left: 0px;
  color: #ff890b;
  font-size: 13pt;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: Calibri;
}
     
li{
  list-style-type: none;
}
    
#right{
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc!important;
  padding-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="list-li">
    <span>Data</Span>
    <p class="test">Book</p>
</li>
<li class="list-li">
    <span>Data</Span>
    <p class="test">Article</p>
</li>
<li class="list-li">
    <span>Data</Span>
    <p class="test">eBook</p>
</li>
<li class="list-li">
    <span>Data</Span>
    <p class="test">Article</p>
</li>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the table?
The list is pre-generated, I do not have control over its structure.

Comment: @NimrodYanai isn't this what you expected ?

Comment: Not by the looks of running the script.
This just colors the rows of the list. What I wanted was to split the list into columns.

Comment: @NimrodYanai once again i Reedit my answer, & I used only `jQuery` without touching the `HTML` part. Please run the **code snippet** to see the final result

Comment: That seems to have done the trick.
I voted it up since it seems to work, but Stack overflow won't accept two answers to the same question and I already deployed the solution above you (which is relatively similar).

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li p.test').each(function(key, val){
        if( $(val).html() == 'eBook' || $(val).html() == 'Book' ) {
            $(val).parent('li').addClass("pull-left");
        } else {
            $(val).parent('li').addClass("pull-right");
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
  var items = $('.list-li');
  
  $.each(items, function(index,item){
    var element = $(item);
    switch( element.find('p.test').text() ){
      case 'Book':
      case 'eBook':
        element.addClass( 'left' );
        break;
      case 'Article':
        element.addClass( 'right' );
        break;
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.left{
  float:left
}

.right{
  float:right
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<li class="list-li">
  <span>Data</Span>
  <p class="test">Book</p>
</li>
<li class="list-li">
  <span>Data</Span>
  <p class="test">Article</p>
</li>
<li class="list-li">
  <span>Data</Span>
  <p class="test">eBook</p>
</li>
<li class="list-li">
  <span>Data</Span>
  <p class="test">Article</p>
</li>
</body>
</html>
```